# Samsung galaxy s5 doesn't turn on my powerbank Platinet 9000mAh

Tags: usb, charging

My powerbank platinet 9000mAh after 5 minutes of standby goes asleep and wakes up when I plug in charger or any device.

When I connect raspberry pi, usb camera, wifi adapter or pendrive my powerbank wakes up. Problem is with my samsung galaxy s5. Nothing happens when plug my smartphone  - powerbank remains in sleeping mode. Firstly I have to connect any other device - then it's wakes up for 5 minutes and I can plug in my samsung and charge.

Where is the problem? There are no  buttons on powerbank.

Comment: It looks like the phone is not recognising powerbank as a powersource for reasons unknown. change the USB cable and see if it helps

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Weird for me is that - I can charge my smartphone but previously I have to wake up powerbank (By plugging for example wifi adapter into powerbank).

Comment: Actually I haven't got any other smartphone nearby so I will check it as fast as it possible. My powerbank have one input 5V/2A and two outputs:
5V/1A & 5V/2.1A - I have checked both. There is no "Iphone port". My stock charger is 5.3V/2.1A, does it matter?

Comment: that shoudn't matter- it seems to be a samsung issue ( though no proof to say so)

Comment: I have tested powerbank with LG g3. Works fine.

Comment: That confirms my gut feeling that it is a Samsung problem - you can write to both Samsung and Powerball guys to see if they can help.